# Deletes the content before the first occurrence of the specified character

Tags: text-processing, sed

I get a very complicated situation, in sort, I have some txt file like this:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <!-- saved from url= 
     (0084)https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Structure/cdd/cddsrv&gt;gi|148227144
         ------------maapaseescssklrsvsvdlnsdpalqidipdalserdkvkftvhtktklpnfknpefdvarfhedf  
         &gt;gi|57525139
         --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         ---------------------------------mqklgegevsmtkeefakmkqeleaeylavfkktvssheiflqriss
         &gt;gi|49899170
         -------------mtsisedsdkekarsvsvdlnndasllidipdalcerdkvkftvhtkttlssfqkpdfsvprqhedf
   </pre><iframe id="canary-tool-tip" frameborder="0" class="fat-sapphire-swordtail- 
   U1xAEvvLch4FZ9B40MDPpa-tool-tip" src="./cd07663_files/mo0yqyx4jxm3k82fauc54s.html" sty>
      <div class="xl-chrome-ext-bar__logo"></div>

      <a id="xl_chrome_ext_download" href="javascript:;" class="xl-chrome-ext-bar__option">&#19979;&#36733;&#35270;&#39057;</a>
      <a id="xl_chrome_ext_close" href="javascript:;" class="xl-chrome-ext-bar__close"></a>
    </div></body></html>
```

Actually, i just want to get the file like this

```
      gi|148227144
      ------------maapaseescssklrsvsvdlnsdpalqidipdalserdkvkftvhtktklpnfknpefdvarfhedf  
      gi|57525139
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ---------------------------------mqklgegevsmtkeefakmkqeleaeylavfkktvssheiflqriss
      gi|49899170
      -------------mtsisedsdkekarsvsvdlnndasllidipdalcerdkvkftvhtkttlssfqkpdfsvprqhedf
```

so I thought I could follow the script `sed -i 's/^.*gi//'`, but I can get the incomplete files, can you give me some advice? appreciate it

Comment: The indentation of input and expected output is inconsistent. I suggest to [edit] your question and insert a line `~~~` before and after the code block pasted to the question. Your example input and output looks incomplete. It is unclear what should happen with the data after the last line shown in the question without changing the indentation. Is it intentional that you expect `gi|148227144` (without `&gt;`) as the first line but `&gt;gi|57525139` etc for the second and third similar lines. Please [edit] your question and add some clarification.

Comment: you say this is a HTML file, but: it's not valid HTML. Your comment started on line 2 ends nowhere.

Comment: actually, it's a HTML file, then i changed HTML format to TXT, in order to make it easier to modify its contens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command `sed -i 's/^.*gi//'` will delete everything upto and including the last occurence of `gi` in a line, because `.*` tries to match as many characters as possible. So if the random string of letters contains `gi`, it will not do what you expect.

I suggest to add the `|` to your pattern, because this random strings don't have bars:

```
sed 's/.*gi|/gi|/'
```

*Note: (1) I removed the `^`, because it is superfluous, as `.*` will always match from the start, and (2) I did put the `gi|` in the replacement because your example shows you want to keep it and (3) I removed the `-i` option and suggest to not add it again until you verified the script does what you want.*